# Is this sentence correct: He ate an apple, carrot, and drank water?

Tags: verbs

> He ate an apple, carrot, and drank water.

Is this sentence correct? If not, how would be the best way to phrase it?

Comment: It's not valid, because you can't switch horses mid-stream re the "predictably repeated, *deleted*" element before *[**he ate a**] carrot* and *[**he**] drank water*. That's true regardless of whether we assume a "deleted" article before ***carrot*** or not (***a** carrot,* or *[**some**] carrot*, depending whether the article is assumed).

Comment: *He ate an apple and [a] carrot, and drank water* is "valid" with or without the repeated article, but I think it's a bit clumsy without. Well, I think it's a bit clumsy anyway, because unavoidably there *can't* be an article before ***water*** (unless it refers to "a bottle of mineral water"). So I'd probably smooth that out a bit with *...and drank **some** water*.

Comment: 'He ate an apple, a carrot, and tea' is grammatical if quite odd-sounding.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Speak for yourself. I will *never* accept that one.

Comment: @FF 'He eats like a horse. He came in after eating a good  lunch, then ate an apple, a carrot, and tea.' Oops, missed the italics for stress.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Doesn't really sound much better than *He went up the stairs and in smoke* to me. But different people will have different standards, I guess.

Comment: One man's near-parallelism is another man's zeugma.